# Is it possible to work with third party Excel add-ins?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a third party add-in installed. There's a button/function on the add-in that I would like to access from a button on my spreadsheet. Possible?

Comment: Automation? google Autohotkey, AutoIt or alternatives(or see https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/ or https://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/)

Comment: Can the button/function be initiated with a key? If yes sendkeys may be an option: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

Comment: Is it a COM add-In or an Excel Add-In? In case of an Excel add-In (.xlam file), you might be able to look in the code via VBA and use something like "Application.Run "'Name_of_Addin.xlam'!NameOfMacro"